# OkHttp is failing on Android over https

Tags: android, iis, ssl, azure-mobile-services, okhttp

Client: Azure Mobile Apps Client 3.0 for Android with OkHttp: 2.5.0

Server: IIS 8 on Windows 10 (for development) using Comodo PositiveSSL, RNI off.

With http, everything works as expected. Going over https causes the following:

The call randomly reaches the server (every few calls, one call succeeds) with the right content. But the response is causing an SSLException in OkHttp wrapped inside IOException.

The content of the exception message "Shutdown" is not descriptive.

I feel that I have similarities with this thread: [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x9524b800: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system)

But, it might be a different issue that I am experiencing.

Comment: This seems a broad topic to discuss. However first clear out any potential doubts. Please check whether your device's date and time are set properly. If not, the SSL certificate validation will fail at the client.

Comment: In addition, are you using a load balancer?

Comment: This is a normal Dev machine, so no load balancer and I tried from an actual phone and from an emulator on the same machine (so same time) and both returned the same results.

Comment: Can u pls check whether your SSL sever is correctly configured using this online test. https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: It is not online, it is an intranet one. It can be accessed via Chrome on Android fine and from other clients

Comment: Hi Adam. Did you have a look at the issues mentioned in the GitHub?

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1582
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1543

Might help you.