# SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x55ad47e080: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library to send request to server's API. My server Url is on HTTPS protocol. Sometimes I get this error while after some minutes i restart app and it fixed.

> SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x55ad47e080: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

I read all answers in stackoverflow and set **TLSSocketFactory.java** but the problem not solved.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;
    private TrustManager[] trustManagers;

    TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException,     NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        generateTrustManagers();
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
        delegate = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    private void generateTrustManagers() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =     TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers =     trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof     X509TrustManager)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
                + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
        }

        this.trustManagers = trustManagers;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }

    X509TrustManager getTrustManager() {
        return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    }
}
```

Why this error occurred and How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42471738/6549598 ?

Comment: not working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`setKeepAlive(true)
setSoKeepalive(HttpParams params, enableKeepalive="true")`

Refer this,
[Connection reset by peer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system)

Comment: Can you explain it more? I don't understand your answer to implement it.

Comment: client = new Socket(hostName, port);
client.setKeepAlive(true);