# SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE sometimes occur

Tags: android, apache, ssl, certificate, asynchttpclient

Well, I am not very knowledgeable about this area of networking, but I tried my best in  searching for similar issue with no success.

I built web services secured with client certificate and made my Android app to connect to them through `AsyncHTTPClient` successfully by creating custom trust manager:

```
private SSLContext getSSLContext(){
      try{
          KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
          InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.i);
          try {
              keyStore.load(in,p);

          } finally {
              in.close();
          }

          KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
          InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
          byte[] der =loadPemCertificate(instream);
          ByteArrayInputStream derInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(der);
          CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
          X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(derInputStream);
          String alias = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
          trustStore.load(null);
          trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
          instream.close();

          KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
          kmf.init(keyStore, pw);
          KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

          TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
          tmf.init(trustStore);



          SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
          sslContext.init(keyManagers, new TrustManager[]{mtm}, null);



          return sslContext;
      }catch (Exception e){


      }

      return null;
  }
```

However, some requests **sometimes** fail. I tried to find any thing special in the failed requests but nothing. 
I just noticed that the failed requests are always requests that get response with chunked transfer encoding. Yet, these requests sometimes do success and sometimes they fail.

Below is the Android error:

```
10-15 15:09:15.319 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xbe44bb40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
10-15 15:09:15.320 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:641 0xc775cfe0:0x00000001)
10-15 15:09:15.320 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err: error:100000d7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:428 0xdd84cb7b:0x00000000)
10-15 15:09:15.320 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
10-15 15:09:15.321 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:789)
10-15 15:09:15.321 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
10-15 15:09:15.321 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
10-15 15:09:15.321 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
10-15 15:09:15.321 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
10-15 15:09:15.322 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
10-15 15:09:15.322 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
10-15 15:09:15.322 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
10-15 15:09:15.322 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
10-15 15:09:15.322 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
10-15 15:09:15.323 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
10-15 15:09:15.323 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
10-15 15:09:15.323 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
10-15 15:09:15.323 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
10-15 15:09:15.323 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
10-15 15:09:15.324 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
10-15 15:09:15.324 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
10-15 15:09:15.324 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
10-15 15:09:15.324 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
10-15 15:09:15.325 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
10-15 15:09:15.325 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-15 15:09:15.325 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
10-15 15:09:15.325 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-15 15:09:15.325 6279-6569/com..tba W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

And below is the Apache error:

```
AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?
```

Finally, below is my custom trust manager:

```
public  class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

protected ArrayList<X509TrustManager> x509TrustManagers = new ArrayList<X509TrustManager>();


protected MyTrustManager(KeyStore... additionalkeyStores) {
    final ArrayList<TrustManagerFactory> factories = new ArrayList<TrustManagerFactory>();

    try {
        // The default Trustmanager with default keystore
        final TrustManagerFactory original = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        original.init((KeyStore) null);
        factories.add(original);

        for( KeyStore keyStore : additionalkeyStores ) {
            final TrustManagerFactory additionalCerts = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            additionalCerts.init(keyStore);
            factories.add(additionalCerts);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


    for (TrustManagerFactory tmf : factories)
        for( TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers() )
            if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager)
                x509TrustManagers.add( (X509TrustManager)tm );


    if( x509TrustManagers.size()==0 )
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find any X509TrustManagers");

}

public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    final X509TrustManager defaultX509TrustManager = x509TrustManagers.get(0);
    defaultX509TrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    for( X509TrustManager tm : x509TrustManagers ) {
        try {
            tm.checkServerTrusted(chain,authType);
            return;
        } catch( CertificateException e ) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    throw new CertificateException();
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    final ArrayList<X509Certificate> list = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
    for( X509TrustManager tm : x509TrustManagers )
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(tm.getAcceptedIssuers()));
    return list.toArray(new X509Certificate[list.size()]);
}
}
```

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31345743/6490462

Comment: @Ibrahim thank you, but this is quite different scenario.

Comment: Your error `Read error: ssl=0xbe44bb40` have been discussed in that answer as well.

Comment: *"AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?"* - this looks for me like access to a resource which requires a client certificate  because this is the only situation Apache requires a renegotiation in my opinion.

Comment: I have this issue when i wanna connecting https through proxy.

Comment: @Mahdi Did you get any solution? I am facing same issue

Comment: @FarmanAliKhan Yes i will post answer.

Comment: @FarmanAliKhan Chec this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896212/1498586

Comment: @Mahdi I think I am using correct certificate. Because it's working on postman.

Comment: @FarmanAliKhan I do not think post man chech it as browser. How about browser?

Comment: It's a post request.