# Https through proxy with OkHttp got handshake error

Tags: ssl, kotlin, https, proxy, okhttp

I'm going to download image with **Glide** library that needs **https** and **proxy** config.
I implemented all anonymous certificates and proxy settings for unsafe client (in my dev environment) but get handshake error. This is my **OkHttpClient** passed to Glide

```
val unsafeOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient
        get() {
            try {
                val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkClientTrusted(
                        chain: Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate>,
                        authType: String
                    ) {
                    }

                @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                override fun checkServerTrusted(
                    chain: Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate>,
                    authType: String
                ) {
                }

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> {
                    return arrayOf()
                }
            })
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())
            val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
            val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            val proxy = Proxy(
                Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(PROXY_URL, PROXY_PORT)
            )
            builder.proxy(proxy)

            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
            builder.hostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true })

            val connectionSpecs = ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
                ).build()

            builder.connectionSpecs(listOf(connectionSpecs))

            return builder.build()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
```

I should mention that **ConnectionSpec** is get from my server configurations. And always i get this error:
Even i used very simple client but result is same.

```
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xbe2b3c68: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:587 0xbe5d2a88:0x00000001)
    error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:580 0xd084f543:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
            ... 23 more
```

I tried too many ways for example exclude okHttp from glide and use OkHttp itself, downgrade okHttp, upgrade all libs ( Retrofit , Glide ) .I found some posts here but cloud not make it works.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3787

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/650

**UPDATED**

As i mentioned all images are open in browser ( with proxy extension) and also i got 200 with Curl like this:

```
curl --insecure -x http://myProxy:9052 -i  https://myimage.png
```

But i find out that TLS version of main server and proxy server are not same. One uses **TLS1.2** and other is **TLS1.1**. So i'm thinking about may this configuration lead to handshake failure cause my request will do not know to handshake with which version! This is my guess and asked the network admin already : "Why we have two different confines for server and proxy!" I'm waitings for their response. If you have any idea please feel free to add comment or post any answer.

Comment: What TLS version is your server using? This looks like SSLv3 which is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: Know i'm thinking that may i scanned main server configs, but may proxy server is using another thing... As i know main server using TSL1.2 but i'm thinking i should check with that proxy ip.

Comment: The error message you see is common if you try to access a plain HTTP resource with HTTPS. The specific code is missing from your question but a typical error when using a proxy is to assume that the proxy itself should be accessed with HTTPS in order to reach a HTTPS-URL. This is the wrong assumption and would lead to such errors you see.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What is wrong assumption? We have a https server that just reachable from proxy address .

Comment: @Mahdi: Can you reach the exact same server through exact the same proxy with the given ciphers but with a different client like curl? Note that the local configuration is kind of strange since you claim to support TLS 1.0 , TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 but then only specify two TLS 1.2 ciphers which essentially means that it could not use TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 anyway. Could you make a packet capture or get SSL debug output from the connection attempt so that one can see what is actually going on? And the issues you cite don't seem to be related to your problem for me.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried with curl --insecure -x myproxy -i myImageUrl and i got 200. I also update to TSL1.2 in android but in android it is not works.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Now i made Curl works and i get 200. I find-out that proxy ip uses another TLS version that main server ( 1.1) and thinking may this cause to handshake mismatch. I contact to server guys and told them why SSL config is not same and they are checking.

Comment: @Mahdi: The TLS on the proxy should be irrelevant since a proxy only forwards the data but does not do anything with TLS itself. The question is, did you use exactly the same ciphers with curl as in your android app? Because you restrict your app for unknown reason to only two ciphers but it looks like you did not have such restriction in your use of curl.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich At begining i used all trus methods and after i get handshake problem i decided to go and cehck server cipers and add they to client. But actualy it is solved now after server side chage their ssl certificate that seems not valid from begining. I'm not sure should i answer this queston by my self and tell it is just about unvalid ssl and stupid backend guy that let my team in this situation for more than one week?? But why images was able to see in browser after proceed with unsafe message?

Comment: @Mahdi: it seems to me that you are mixing multiple problems together: server side failures in the certificate setup which caused the skippable certificate warnings in the browser and failure in the handshake likely caused by your limited choice of ciphers in the client (while the browser had not this specific problem).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I was goting the same error when i was trust all ciphers then i decide to specifie servers cipers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After strugle with many thing from client side, backed team set a **valid certificate** that make my problem solved. 
I mean they did **not** use **self-sigend** certificate but they used an **invalid certificate**! That is why i got hand shake error and in browser we can passed this error by accept responcibility of danger and click proceed button.

### So if you see the same problem: Handshake error but you can proceed it in browser with my situation lets chech SSL certificate first to save time!