# Retrofit 2 - SSLException instead of 413

Tags: java, android, nginx, retrofit2, http-status-code-413

I'm trying to send a file (230MB) to `NGinx/1.10.2` server.

The server is configured to handle max 200MB.

I send a file like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/test")
Completable test(
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
);
```

My retrofit timeouts: Read/Write/Connect - 200 SEC

My log:

```
--> POST https://testserver.com/api/test
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=4efbe174-e228-4dc7-aeec-d6dbe4ab4302
Content-Length: 230757873
Authorization: Bearer ...
--> END POST
```

Now I expect error with 413 status code. Unfortunately, I receive:

```
<-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x76c8f32400: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

after 30 sec.

If I use `Postman` to send this file then it works like charm - 413 after few millis. So I don't think it is server problem

```
Retrofit version: 2.4.0
OkHttp version: 3.10.0
```

Request part:

```
public Completable test(File file) {
    Map<String, RequestBody> map = getInfo();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getMimeType(file.toString())), file);
    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), body);

    return retrofit.create(Api.class)
            .flatMapCompletable(api -> api.test(map, fileToUpload));
}
```

Comment: Show the RequestBody part of your code

Comment: Try this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system