# D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x64e3c938: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, ssl, retrofit, retrofit2

> D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x64e3c938: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

I'm getting this error on an Android 4.2.2 device. While running the same application on other devices, it works fine.
Please Help.

```
public static Retrofit getClient(final Context context, final Server newServer) {
    if(retrofit == null || server == null || !getServer().equals(newServer) || tok != null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

        okHttpClient.addInterceptor( new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                  String hh=tok.replace("\"", "");  //For removing the " from the token
                    Request newRequest = chain
                            .request()
                            .newBuilder()
                            .addHeader(HTTP_AUTH_HEADER,"Bearer " + hh) //token use for the Authentication.
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                }
            });


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getBaseUrl(context, server))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
private static String getBaseUrl(Context context, Server newServer) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    server = newServer; // update server address
    if(server != null && server.getAddress() != null) {
        return builder.append(server.getAddress()).toString();
    } else { // set default address
        return builder.append(BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS).toString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No code and no stacktrace.

Comment: @SamzSakerz yes Sir Duplicate issue its not working on Android version 4.2.2

Comment: what is the SSL protocol version of your server? is that `TLSv1.2`?

Comment: @ZahidulIslam yes it is TLSv1.2

Comment: You have to implement it manually

Comment: @ZahidulIslam hi m trying below code and now my error is change

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4 and Lower devices don't have default `TLSv1.2` support. So, you need to make it manually.

First write down the following method.

```
    public static OkHttpClient.Builder enableTls12OnPreLollipop(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            client.sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()), (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);

            ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                    .build();

            ConnectionSpec csslv3 = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.SSL_3_0)
                    .build();

            List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
            specs.add(cs);
            specs.add(csslv3);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);

            client.connectionSpecs(specs);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.e("OkHttpTLSCompat", "Error while setting TLS 1.2", exc);
        }
    }
    return client;
}
```

Now after this line `OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);` add the following code.

```
okHttpClient = enableTls12OnPreLollipop(okHttpClient);
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Showing Same error

Comment: client.sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()),What is the secound paratmeter?);

Comment: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x64e0bc50: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x64193c38:0x00000000)

Comment: @NeerajUpadhyay , Share the URL or public IP that you are using for API.

Comment: @NeerajUpadhyay , Also, i modify the code. You can give a try. If it will not work then share the URL.