# Retrofit not working on specific versions of android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a problem with Retrofit on my emulator running Android 4.3 and my device is on Android 4.4.2 while the same code runs normally on another emulator with Android 7.1.1

Each time I try to execute the `get` request I get a timeout exception.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/2606:4700:30::681c:3f5 (port 443) after 10000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The code is below

```
public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

    @GET("posts")
    Call<ArrayList<Post>> getPosts();
}
```

and the call to the api

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
Call<ArrayList<Post>> call = api.getPostes();
Log.i("RequestUrl", call.request().url().toString());
call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Post>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Post>> call, Response<ArrayList<Post>> response) {
        mPostsList.setValue(response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Posts", "Error occurred", t);
    }
});
```

Comment: which version of Retrofit are you using?

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354256

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It reads `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`, which at first suggests to raise the client's connect-timeout value, as it is being explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41480885/549372) - but when reviewing the current [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/platform/AndroidPlatform.kt) of `okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform`... this rather hints for incompatible protocols.

The server's [SSL certificate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jsonplaceholder.typicode.com&s=2606%3a4700%3a30%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a681c%3a3f5&latest) supports `TLS 1.0`, as it would be required for Android 4.x (there's no problem on their side); the problem rather is, that the current version  of `OkHttp3` does not support `TLS 1.0` anymore and therefore the handshake won't ever take place (that's why it throws such a misleading `SocketTimeoutException` instead of a `SSLHandshakeException`).

---

With `OkHttp3` `3.12.x`, it should still be supported with the default configuration `MODERN_TLS` -

but one could instruct `OkHttp3` `3.13.x` to use configuration `COMPATIBLE_TLS` instead:

```
/* ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS is the default value */
List tlsSpecs = Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS);

/* providing backwards-compatibility for API lower than Lollipop: */
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    tlsSpecs = Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
}

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionSpecs(tlsSpecs)
    .build();
```

One also has to set it as the client for `Retrofit`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .setClient(client)
    .build();
```

See the [TLS Configuration History](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/TLS-Configuration-History) for the available protocol support, per `OkHttp3` version. As it seems, `3.12.x` even already supports `TLS 1.3`, as it will in future be required for Android `Q`. It might not even be required to down-grade `OkHttp3`, because `MODERN_TLS` of `3.12.x` still supports `TLSv1`, while in `3.13.x` it had been moved into `COMPATIBLE_TLS`;  still uncertain about `3.14.x`.

Even with current versions of `OkHttp3`, one could possibly still add the desired `TLS 1.0` protocol back into `ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS`, since this is an `ArrayList` with a method `.add()` - without any guarantee, that there won't be further incompatibilities; `3.12.x` might still be the best choice for supporting Android 4.x onward and there might even be back-ports of newer features.

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong. You can instruct OkHttp to use `COMPATIBLE_TLS`, see https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS. That should work with TLS 1.0. Beware that you use anything newer than OkHttp 3.12 because that's the last one that supports Android 4.x and earlier.

Comment: @aha `MODERN_TLS` of `3.12.x` still supports `TLSv1`, while in `3.13.x` it had been added into `COMPATIBLE_TLS`... so this problem only applies to the default configuration `MODERN_TLS`. version `3.13.x` should still work, while not using the default configuration; not that certain about `3.14.x`.

Answer (score 8):

If you use android 9 (Pie) or android SDK above 28 and get the issue on over the api call through Retrofit.

Add this line to your manifest `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
[Retrofit Issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2925)

Comment: Okay but we need this configuration only to connect with api without SSL (http)

Comment: Attribute usesCleartextTraffic is only used in API level 23 and higher

Answer (score 1):

Android prior to 21 has some missing SSL and Retrofit wont work. Using google services you can update the device protocols after that the HTTP request will work

```
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0'
     //remember to add the library in your dependencies

        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$currentVersion'

        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, new ProviderInstallListener() {

            @Override

            public void onProviderInstalled() {

                //Do your http request here

            }


            @Override

            public void onProviderInstallFailed(int errorCode, Intent recoveryIntent) {

                //sad face :C is sad

            }

        });
```

Comment: Docs https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider and full discussion https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372 Maybe Im missing somethinf, be kind to point out please @MartinZeitler

Comment: I would guess that @cutiko refers to the fact that before KitKat there wasn't support for TLS 1.2 https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/working-with-tls-1-2-on-android-4-4-and-lower-f4f5205629a