# how to use Tls12 Socket Factory in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tls1.2

Am trying to work with TLS 1.2 for Android 4.4 and Lower in kotlin and after hours of search I found [this](https://gist.github.com/ankushg/8c0c3144318b1c17abb228d6211ba996) class which is as they say in this [article](https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/working-with-tls-1-2-on-android-4-4-and-lower-f4f5205629a) is the ultimate solution But I have no idea how to use it

Comment: You have to install it in the first place. I've once explained the backwards-compatibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547248/retrofit-not-working-on-specific-versions-of-android/55667454#55667454).

Comment: just tried your code . I still got ` SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x66d3a6a0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer `

Comment: That web-server might enforce SNI (and there's nothing you can do about it on the client-side, except dropping the support for such obsolete devices); you could only provide a backwards compatible API endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system